# How to move index data between Elastic Search environments

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic search, and need to move data for an index from my local environment to acceptance environment.
How can I do this? using the ES Apis?
Is there a way I can export data and then import it?

Comment: remote reindexing, or logstash pipeline should solve it easily. I explain in detail with the answer if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your two options are either;

1. snapshot and restore - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-restore.html
2. remote reindex - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/reindex-upgrade-remote.html